# Why does this method call return the same reference every time it’s called?

Tags: java, methods, singleton

```
public class SomeClass {  

    private static final SomeClass INSTANCE = new SomeClass();

    private SomeClass() {} 

    public static SomeClass getInstance() {return INSTANCE;}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getInstance()); 
    }
}
```

Why does the `getInstance` method always return the same reference every time?

Comment: How are we meant to know why the code was written that way? Yes, it always returns the same reference - this is basically a singleton...  but we can't tell why, as we have no context.

Comment: For future reference: please consider translating your code samples. For better or worse English is the lingua franca of programming and the (at least) de facto language for SO, and in more complicated questions it makes it harder to tell what's going on when most people answering can't read your identifiers.

Comment: @millimoose I just translated his identifiers into English using what I *think* he meant for them to be.

Comment: the answer is easy , cause it's static , is class level , it's only created when the class is loaded, not when instaces are created

Comment: is exactly what I mean , thx for the help, next time I'll know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that the field `INSTANCE` is both `static` and `final`.

`static` means its scope is bound to the enclosing class, and not any single instance of that class. (Even though you're not creating any instances of it anyway.) In a running Java program, there's only one of each *class*, even though a class may have many *instances*.

`final` means that the value of this field cannot be changed after it's initialised.

Because it's `static`, there's only one "slot" for the object, and because it's `final` the contents of this slot will never change, which is why returning those contents will always return the same thing.

Comment: the static part ensures that a pointer to the same object is returned each time

Comment: @bas Nope, **both** modifiers assure that. If the field were not `final` it could be reassigned between calls to `getInstance()`. Admittedly not in the OP's example which doesn't have any code doing that but for theorethical exam questions it's better to be thorough.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning a reference to a constant (`INSTANCE`), and your `getInstance` method returns that constant, so yes, it always returns the same reference.

Comment: You’re exactly right. BTW, I just translated his identifiers into English to make it easier on others, so you might want to edit your answer to track that.

Comment: @tchrist thanks for the warning! I've actually edited a bit over your edit :P

Comment: Yah, ok. I still use normal identifier rules in Java, notstuffthatistoohardtoread.

Comment: @tchrist I get your point, it might look harder to read, but it's the [conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367). Same way the code should be in English, as you pointed out earlier.

Comment: That may be so, but I won’t use them. They’re nutty.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you have declared the instance

`private static final SomeClass INSTANCE = new SomeClass();`

as `final` and `static`   , so the instance will be allocated a **single memory** and that also be **constant**, therefore it is using **singleton** pattern

Take a look at this stuff  -
**[Implementation of Singleton Pattern Class in Java Introduction](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/433c33/implementation-of-singleton-pattern-class-in-java-introduct/)**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will return the same reference always as long as the class is loaded. Its `static final`

Answer (score 0):

`INSTANTA` is declared `final`, which means its value cannot be changed once it has been initialized. Hence, program guarantees that `getInstanta` returns same instance always.

Answer (score 0):

You declared both method and constant `static`. This means it is a member of the class instead of an object created from that class. As the class only exists once it will always return the same object. Furthermore since your variable is `final` it can never be assigned to a new object.